# Zoomin out of site (automatically in the html code)

Tags: html, css, zooming, scaling

I have a webpage (html + css file). When it's shown in its native zoom it doesn't look good. I need to zoom-out (twice click ctrl+-) to get it look good.

Hence, I want this zoomed-out format become the native zoom of the site, namely, that people seeing my site will see it that way by default (on Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer).

**Question:** Is there a way to do this? What is the simplest way to do this?
(I don't really code well html/css. I used a free template to build my own site.)

Comment: Well, I prefer not to go public :)

Comment: Its stack overflow, not the stock exchange :-)

Comment: @Dilworth, sorry could not  resist

Comment: @AnaMaria, it's okay, I didn't get the joke anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Its because your CSS is not changing according to the resolution

so use media queries

http://mediaqueri.es/

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: I don't see how media query can help. The media query is just a condition which will answer either a true or false value. But then, according to the answer, I need to reduce the zoom factor. But my problem is that I don't know how to reduce the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

Use media queries to write different styles for different screen resolutions.

also, use ems and percentages for font-size widths, padding, margin etc.. so that when you zoom you page it gets changed relative to the parent  as per resolution.

Comment: Dito. Can't see how media query help here. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@media query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
@media tv and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
@media (min-width: 700px), handheld and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

[Further more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

You can also use [window.resizeTo(iWidth, iHeight)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.resizeTo?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.resizeTo) method to resize your browser window.

Comment: Thanks. Does window.resize controls also the zoom of pictures?

Comment: Oh, btw, I don't want the Browser Window to change of course, only the content of my site.

Comment: About media query, I don't need a conditioned change of zoom. I need only one zoom. I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: If so, use @media query.

Comment: I don't understand how media query functions here: even if my site discovers the parameters of the browser, then I need to change zoom. But how?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Trick that you can use in CSS, however remember that this will  zoom out the HTML from the centre and mess up with the total alignment of you site.
However im sure if you play around a bit you may find this to your advantage.

CSS

```
html {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    transform: scale(1.4);
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GdYMH/4/)